# Calculating the ratio of each item to the column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a data like this:

```
col1 value
A     2
B     4
C     8   
D     6
```

I want to calculate the ratios to the column total

```
col1 value
A     10%
B     20%
C     40% 
D     30%
```

How can I do this with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*, value * 100.0 / sum(value) over () as perentage
from t;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Gordon. What happens if I want to calculate the ratio of value of A to value of B, value B to value C and value C to value D? Is it again doable with the window function?

Comment: @realkes . . . I think you have already asked the question, but `lead()` is the answer.